# VS2022 keeps resetting source control plugin to none

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

Been having this problem every since we ported our solution to GitHub. Previously the solution was managed through SVN, and this was no problem. It always selected SVN as it was supposed to.

I've used the extension "VisualSVN for Visual Studio 2022", but have uninstalled it, as I suspected it was the culprit. But the only change, was that it changed to "none" instead of "SVN".

If i select Git as the source control plugin, saves, and restart the solution. It will have gone back to "none".

I have removed the following section, i found lingering in my .sln file

```
GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
    Svn-Managed = True
    Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
EndGlobalSection
```

For now i keep having to select the source control on every restart of the solution.